Horror/Suspense movie where killer lives inside victim's house
I watched this years ago (Mid 2000s in the USA), but some key things stuck out.
I think in the beginning, someone drowns in a lake behind the house, but then he comes back? and is living in the house. He has an elaborate path that allows him to walk in the house by going between the walls. He doesn't kill anyone, or attempt until the end. I believe he gets into the house while no one is there and leaves notes, moves objects etc..
I remember the finale had this guy sitting under the floor of the main entrance where he pulls a cord and the floor drops out on a victim. In addition to many homemade weapons, the killer created a wooden frame with saw blades on in that the victim fell into.
I can't really remember how it ends, but some other parts that stuck out are:

I think the killer was trying to romance the girl by playing music in a canoe before he drowned
The killer gets into the girls room by moving a dresser and left a note
The mother of the people being 'stalked' is in a mental health hospital for most of the movie


Could you be looking for Housebound (2014)? Some of the details fit, like the plot that a killer is living in the walls of a house, and leaves notes/ moves objects. I don't recall any drownings in the movie though.

@onewho Nope, I saw this around 2004-2009ish. I don't think the killer was a ghost, it was really weird. I remember a drowning and then this guy was in the house, I think he was obsessed with the teenage daughter (subsequently the one he was trying to romance). The mother is also only present in the movie when they visit her at the hospital, but I don't believe the house is why she was in there.
Also the killer looked like a normal person, no costumes or anything.

@madmada I was intentionally leaving certain details out of my comment as to not reveal any spoilers.

Good thinking, but I meant that the movie can't possibly be it, since OP described how he killed some people at the end.

Asked around and just found it.
It was the lifetime movie Christina's House (2000). I'm going to read the wiki synopsis to try and determine if the drowning was actually there or I just made it up from bad recollection. 
Edit: The drowning was 

 when the killer Howie killed Christina's friend and put the body in the lake.


You can select your own answer as the 'accepted' one by clicking on the checkmark to turn it from grey to green.

@aryxus I know, I have a 2 day wait period though.

Oops; sorry! It's not always easy keeping all these rules in my head. Especially the ones like that which don't make much sense. I mean, making you wait two days isn't going to force you to accept any other answer that arrives in the meantime.
